# mysql dump runs, but does nothing

Tags: centos, mysql

I am trying to restore a database using mysqldump, but nothing seems to happen.  I get some output on the screen, but the program stops before it imports anything and does not report any errors.

I am trying to restore a dump using the syntax

```
mysqldump --log-error=/root/dumplog --verbose --user=myuser mydatabasename < /root/dump.sql
```

I get no entries in the MySQL log, and in dumplog, all I get is this:

```
-- Connecting to localhost...
-- Disconnecting from localhost...
```

The dump file is like 15mb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't use mysqldump to restore.  To restore you would do:

```
mysql -uUser -p dbname < /path/to/file.sql
```

Comment: Sure you can, it's even documented in the manual - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: What section of that are you referring to?  Its there to make the backups you can restore from, but the only mention of restore is with hotcopy and when dumping it for an upcoming restore.  If you look at this part of the manual, it has you recovering with mysql... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/recovery-from-backups.html